# How to use JavaScript libraries with Sapper/Svelte?

Tags: svelte

Using Sappers export feature to build a static site, I would love to be able to use JavaScript libraries like [Conversational Form](https://github.com/space10-community/conversational-form) and [GSAP](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS). Trying to add them to `client.js` or my components, I can't access the `window` object.

How do I best approach this?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard way is to `import` those libraries into your components:

```js
<script>
  import { TweenMax, Power2, TimelineLite } from 'gsap';

  export default {
    oncreate() {
      // use GSAP in here, or in custom methods
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: This was exactly the hint I needed. Thanks a lot Rich.